# How can we use Array.prototype.map on strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I know we can't use `Array.prototype.map` on strings like

```js
const str = 'MY NAME IS USER';
const result = str.map(c => c); // "Uncaught TypeError: str.map is not a function"
console.log(result);
```

This will result in error states:

> "Uncaught TypeError: str.map is not a function"

But today I came across a code snipet where I can use `call` `Array.prototype` on `strings`

```js
const str = 'MY NAME IS USER';

const x = Array.prototype.map
  .call(str, (c, i) => {
    if (str.indexOf(c, i + 1) == -1 && str.lastIndexOf(c, i - 1) == -1)
      return c;
  })
  .join('');

console.log(x);
```

**In this snippet I couldn't get how `Array.prototype.map` called on `string` str.**

Comment: `Array.prototype.map.call` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: First error is thrown simply because there is no `.map` implemented for strings. That does not mean you can't access `"MY NAME IS USER"[2]`

Comment: `.map()` acts on `this`. `.call()` sets the content of `this` to what ever you pass it as first argument. You can access characters of a string with `[index]` - which is what `.map()` does internally.

Comment: The string will be cast into an `array` where each char in that string will be an element in that `array` (`str` after `map` call becomes: `['M', 'Y', ' ', 'N', 'A', 'M', 'E', ' ', 'I', 'S, ' ', 'U', 'S', 'E', 'R']`)

Comment: @ths No, at no point is the string "cast to an array", and the result of that code is also not what you say.

Comment: @deceze i didn't say that this is the result! I said what will `str` (the variable) become after  calling `Array.prototype.map.call` on `str` which basically is that the first iteration of `map` will put "M" into the argument `c` of the `map` callback. `Array.prototype.map.call` here will basically spread the string.

Comment: @ths _"Array.prototype.map.call here will basically spread the string"_ - No, it won't.

Comment: @Andreas what will it do then ?

Comment: @ths It simply iterates over `this` using `this.length` and `this[i]`, [which works for both arrays and strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73687673/476).

Comment: @deceze isn't that an array like situation in the end!

Comment: why this question is voted to close(Not reproducible or was caused by a typo). Is there anything wrong with this question...

Comment: @ths You can access offsets in a string like an array, but at no point does the string get "cast to an actual array".

Comment: @deceze i get your idea, seems clearer now. Anyway, I was trying to simplify things as possible. Thanks for that fruitful discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object methods work with `this`. The `map` function is implemented something like:

```
function map(cb) {
    var r = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
         r.push(cb(this[i]));
    }
    return r;
}
```

When you invoke a function with `.call`, you can decide what the `this` context should be. Even though the `this` in array methods is *usually* an array, you're overriding that here. And the way `map` is implemented—how it uses `this`—happens to work both for arrays and strings.

Answer (score 1):

@deceze already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73687673/58186) your question. Additional, if you want to use `map` (or any Array prototype method) 'directly' on a string, [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) it:

```js
const str = 'MY NAME IS USER';
const x = [...str].reduce( (a, c) => a.concat(c.toLowerCase()), ``);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: Thanks for the another solution but this I knew. It will give us array of string because strings are iterable